# IIS 7 stops working after ColdFusion 10 Upgrade

Tags: iis-7, coldfusion, installation, coldfusion-10, applicationhost

So after reading Adobe's documentation about how seemless it would be to go from ColdFusion 8 to ColdFusion 10, last week I gave it a go. I went through the installation process as I have with other versions of the language. At the end it displayed a message.

> Installed Successfully, but with errors

In the log file that was created, I saw the following error:

> Migration Error: : Check that "C:\ColdFusion8" is a valid directory and is an installation of either ColdFusion MX 6 or ColdFusionMX 7

For the record, my installation of ColdFusion 8 is in that directory.
When I opened the Web Server Configuration Tool, it was not bound to IIS, even though I had specified "All IIS Sites" during installation. When I tried to run the configuration tool manually, it would not recognize IIS.

So then I try to access IIS only to discover that IIS is no longer serving up web pages and I can't even expand the tree in IIS to view the sites. It just spins.

So I uninstallled ColdFusion 10....and IIS remained broken.
There were several references to ColdFusion 10 still in the *applicationhost.config* file which had to be removed before IIS would respond.

I haven't found anyone else who has had this particular installation problem with ColdFusion so any suggestions would be greatful.

---

### UPDATED

I re-downloaded the installation files from Adobe's website to ensure I had the latest builds. I experienced the following.

I also made a backup copy of my *applicationHost.config* file before beginning.

---

Running the 64 bit installer file (on a Win Server 2008 64 bit OS) it did install, but the migration from ColdFusion 8 failed. This time it didn't appear to damage IIS. But I still received 1 Warning and 1 NonFatalError as follows:

> Migration Error: : Check that "C:\ColdFusion8" is a valid directory and is an installation of either ColdFusion MX 6 or ColdFusionMX 7
>
> Migration Error:
>
> Status: WARNING
>
> Additional Notes: WARNING - Could not migrate settings from previous version of ColdFusion
>
> Custom Action:
>
> com.macromedia.ia.action.MigrateColdFusionAction
>
> Status: ERROR
>
> Additional Notes: ERROR - class com.macromedia.ia.action.MigrateColdFusionAction NonfatalInstallException null

Since I'd really like to migrate my CF8 settings, I uninstalled the ColdFusion 10 and THAT is when my IIS rendered this message:

> Getting 403: Forbidden Access Is Denied Error

Restoring my *applicationHost.config* file restored IIS to the way it was.

---

So with few options left, I tried the 32 bit installer just to see what would happen.

This time I got this message during the installation process

> Cannot configure IIS connector. Enable the required option ASP.NET, ISAPI Extensions and ISAPI Filter in IIS under Windows Features and try again.

Ok...here's the thing. I had already set all those, as well as the *CGI* and even *IIS 6 Metabase Compatibility* enabled in IIS so it seems the installer isn't recognizing them. And yes, I was running the installer as Administrator.

---

So....sorry if that was long winded. Any ideas?

Comment: This is not a programming question, it's a server admin question - asking on [SF] is far more likely to get responses than asking here.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I wasn't aware of Server Fault until now. I've posted my question there and will take this one down once either of them get an answer. Unfortunatly nobody seems to be having this problem. Guess I'll be shelling out for Adobe tech support next weekend if I hear nothing else.

Comment: Yeah, there's a whole bunch of sites related to Stack Overflow, skip to the end of the page and you'll see a bunch of coloured squares next to the different sites...